# Creating a longer list in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a question for a code I'm writing to highlight certain words and phrases. The code is checking for a significant number of phrases. I have the list, but I'm wondering how to fit them all in a single array. When I try to paste them all in the array, it gets to the end of the line and it won't work. therefore, I have to create multiple arrays. This is taking a lot of time because I likely need to create 30+ arrays based on the massive number of phrases it's checking.

```
Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim WordList

WordList = Array("wordx", "wordy", "wordz") ' 

For i = 0 To UBound(WordList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
```

Comment: If you have that many words/phrases to find, you might try a `Dictionary` instead of an array.

Comment: You can Concatenate the string using `|` then split them into a Array. Like make a string `ABC|DEF|GHI|MKL|HAHAH|BLAH|BLAU` and then use `Wordlist = Split(mystring, "|")`

Comment: Don't use an array.  Use a collection irrespective of where your strings come from.  To create the collection put all the .add statements in a single function and make the function return the collection.  Alternatively, as you are using word, put all your words as a list in a word document (one phrase to a line) then you can do something like For Each my_para in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs: collection.add my_para.moveend until(unit:=wdcharacter,count:=-1).range.text: next.

Comment: You've gotten some suggestions, but without knowing how you plan to store / manage this list it's difficult to know which might be the best approach. Do you plan on hard-coding this in the macro? Is this code just for you, or will others be using it and maybe need to change the list?